# I am not able to install tensorflow=1.4.1

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

Hi when I run this commands
`pip install tensorflow==1.4.1`

It not run and give the following error

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.4.1 (from versions: 0.12.0rc0, 0.12.0rc1, 0.12.0, 0.12.1, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.1.0rc0, 1.1.0rc1, 1.1.0rc2, 1.1.0, 1.2.0rc0, 1.2.0rc1, 1.2.0rc2, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.3.0rc0, 1.3.0rc1, 1.3.0rc2, 1.3.0, 1.4.0rc0, 1.4.0rc1, 1.4.0, 1.5.0rc0, 1.5.0rc1, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.6.0rc0, 1.6.0rc1, 1.6.0, 1.7.0rc0, 1.7.0rc1, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.8.0rc0, 1.8.0rc1, 1.8.0, 1.9.0rc0, 1.9.0rc1, 1.9.0rc2, 1.9.0, 1.10.0rc0, 1.10.0rc1, 1.10.0)
>   No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.4.1

please tell me that how I can install in cpu

Comment: as the error shows, there is no version 1.4.1, you would probably want to have 1.4.0. Also you can choose any other version from the above stack trace.

Comment: Try another version from version list, or just pip install tensorflow

Comment: For tensorflow 1.4.1 windows binary wheel had not been built. If you want to have a compatible version of tensorflow on Windows, 1.4.0 seems a logical choice as there are no changes between 1.4.0 and 1.4.1 related to behaviour on Windows. See also this [TF issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/15342). Also would you add a [tag:windows] tag to the post?

Answer (score 4):

This post is probably related to Tensorflow installation on Windows.

Tensorflow 1.4.1 was not built for Windows since changes introduced between 1.4.0 and 1.4.1 do not affect the behaviour of Tensorflow on Windows platform. If you want to have a compatible version of tensorflow, version 1.4.0 seems to be a logical choice.

So if running on Windows try instead

```
 pip install tensorflow==1.4.0
```

This issue has been discussed on Tensorflow issue tracker as [#15342](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/15342).