# Install an older version of Tensorflow GPU

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, pip, gpu

I was tring to install older version of tensorflow gpu on windows 10:

```
pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.4.0
```

And I get an error like  [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51797518/i-am-not-able-to-install-tensorflow-1-4-1) impling there is no windows version

And I'm wondering if there is a way to get the list of functionning windows tensorflow version

Thanks in advance

**Edits**

It seems that tensorflow GPU v1.4.0 doesn't work on python 3.7 therefore creating another enviromment and downgrading your python version to 3.6 may resolve the issue.

by using anaconda you can do it this way

```
conda create -n py36 python=3.6
conda activate py36
pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.4.0
```

*note that another older version of CUDA is required for older version of tensorflow (I had to install CUDA 8.0)*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python and pip, list all versions of a package that's available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888027/python-and-pip-list-all-versions-of-a-package-thats-available)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you go to the [pypi page](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-gpu/1.4.0/#files) of `tensorflow 1.4`, you can see, that only `whl` files up to python 3.6 are available. I am guessing that you are either using 3.7 or 3.8. That is why

```
pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.4.0
```

is not working for you. There simply is no installation candidate for `tensorflow-gpu` for python versions other than 2.7, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5, 3.6

I think you have two options, since you mentioned that you have `conda`:

**Create an environment**

Create an environment that is using `python 3.6` and then use `pip install` like you originally intended

```
conda create -n py36 python=3.6
conda activate py36
pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.4.0
```

**Try a channel that has your version**

You can use the [search function on the website](https://anaconda.org/search?q=tensorflow+gpu) to locate a channel that has your specific version available, for `1.4`, you should be able to do:

```
conda install -c cjj3779 tensorflow-gpu
```

No version specification neccessary, as the only available version in that channel is 1.4

Comment: Yes, you were totallly right: it seems that tensorflow 1.4.0 doesn't run on python 3.7

Comment: @JeffWinchell Yes, but the question was about 1.4 not 1.14

Answer (score 2):

## Option 1: Installing with pip, but only available versions

Looking at the error message `pip` created it shows that `tensorflow-gpu==1.4.0` is not available.

In order to see available versions, check the versions within parenthesis:

```
    ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-gpu==1.4.0
 (from versions: 1.13.0rc1, 1.13.0rc2, 1.13.1, 1.13.2, 1.14.0rc0, 1.14.0rc1, 1.14.0,
 1.15.0rc0, 1.15.0rc1, 1.15.0rc2, 1.15.0rc3, 1.15.0, 2.0.0a0, 2.0.0b0, 2.0.0b1,
 2.0.0rc0, 2.0.0rc1, 2.0.0rc2, 2.0.0, 2.1.0rc0, 2.1.0rc1, 2.1.0rc2)
 ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-gpu==1.4.0
```

Then select the one fits you from available ones:

```
pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.14.0
```

## Option 2: Installing with Conda

Go with this tutorial: https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/installing-anaconda-windows

After you install Anaconda to Windows:

1) Create an environment:

```
conda create -n tf_gpu python=3.6 anaconda
```

2) Activate this environment:

```
conda activate tf_gpu
```

3) Install tf-gpu 1.4:

```
conda install tensorflow-gpu=1.4
```

Comment: I already made an installation of tensorflow 1.14 with anaconda. But the script that I want to run was initialy made for 1.4 and it doesn't run on 1.14

Comment: Then you need to go for Option-2. Create an environment and install your desired version (1.4) to that environment.

Comment: @Felox What’s the issue, then? If you know how to install a specific version of a package with Conda, then just install version 1.4.

Comment: conda install tensorflow-gpu=1.4.0 gives                     PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - tensorflow-gpu=1.4.0

Comment: try this: conda install tensorflow-gpu=1.4 -c conda-forge

Comment: If it does not work add conda forge: ```conda config --append channels conda-forge``` and try to update conda: ```conda update conda```. Then retry!

Comment: I run the two instruction before trying the installation, but I still got a `PackagesNotFoundError`

Comment: Can you see version 1.4.1 in the output of ```conda search tensorflow-gpu -c conda-forge``` ?

Comment: @isydmr 1.4.1 is only availabe in conda-forge/linux-64 not the win64 channel