# Where are there instructions for installing previous versions of TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, installation

I've seen some similar questions like [install-an-older-version-of-tensorflow-gpu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59650012/install-an-older-version-of-tensorflow-gpu).

But I'm looking for the full instructions like that for the current TensorFlow version at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip.

This is important b/c the instructions have changed slightly through the years (e.g. current instruction says to **pip install nvidia-cudnn-cu11==8.6.0.163**, but previous instructions I think said to install cudnn via conda...I don't recall for sure).

Where are the complete instructions for installing previous versions of TensorFlow and setting them up to work w/ GPU?